Someone setup a terrible Documents Hierarchy in Sharepoint Online other ways to deal with it?
So there's a document hierarchy at work in Teams and in Sharepoint; it's just bad.
It is formed like this:
Documents > Team > Audit Info > Year > Location
The problem is; that if you want to switch the year, and not the location, you have to go to the two layers up to the parents' parent item, go to your year, and then from the long, long list of locations find your location again.
If one were working on the command line this efficiency nightmare would never ensue; there must be another way.
I also considered using the handy Add to OneDrive button so I could do just that; but then it has the possibility of downloading everything, from every year, from every property if I were to simply search my OneDrive.
I am aware that there are [group policies/administrative templates for OneDrive][1] to skip over and ignore certain directories and files (which doesn't seem to work in my experience).
Also, Microsoft and OEMs seem to want to force you to buy either external hard drives or use the cloud; so my laptops drive isn't big enough to handle such nonsense.
I can also use Powershell Modules to download the files; but it's not super convenient as you have to set it up individually every single time you want to download a file.
Is there another way around this?
Either using one of the ideas above or something else to make this more manageable?
It's making it difficult to consolidate information for our audits.
